# Novel with inexperienced soldiers in orbit

Tags: story-identification, novel, space, space-station

All I remember of it is a scene where experienced Earth soldiers in spacesuits who are, however, not experienced in space combat are trying to assault a rotating space station. They jump off from one part to another and most are killed by collision or drifting off into space.

Comment: There was a scene in [Consider Phlebas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consider_Phlebas) where a character forgets that his anti-grav doesn't work when on a space station.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Can you remember when you read this? It's vaguely reminiscent of the Russian assault on the Stone in Greg Bear's *Eon*.

Comment: There's also a similar scene in Descent Of Anansi, if I remember correctly

Comment: It's been a while since I've read either, but it also reminds me of the final battle in James P. Hogan's _Two Faces of Tomorrow_ (except the soldiers were fairly competent and I don't recall accidental collisions), and Niven & Barnes' _Descent of Anansi_ (except it was a space shuttle, not a space station).

Comment: Reminds me of John Ringo's 'East of the Sun, West of the Moon'.

Comment: IIRC that is very similar to an action scene in "Semper Mars" by Ian Douglas 2012.